# Swift. How do i get the type of node.children?

Tags: swift, types, sprite-kit, children, skspritenode

I have this as my code:

```
for child in viewsArray[i].children {
    let childNode = child as! SKSpriteNode
    if childNode.color == UIColor.blackColor() && childNode.alpha == 1 {
        childNode.alpha = 0.5
    }
}
```

It gives me this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'SKCropNode' (0x1a04415a0) to 'SKSpriteNode' (0x1a0441230).

So my question is how can I check the type of the children before I write `let childNode = child as! SKSpriteNode`, so I can avoid this error?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Functional Programming here's the code

```
viewsArray[i].children
    .flatMap { $0 as? SKSpriteNode }
    .filter { $0.color == .blackColor() && $0.alpha == 1 }
    .forEach { $0.alpha = 0.5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for child in viewsArray[i].children {
    guard let childNode = child as? SKSpriteNode else { continue }
    if childNode.color == UIColor.blackColor() && childNode.alpha == 1 {
        childNode.alpha = 0.5
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes it will! See the docs! "The else clause of a guard statement is required, and must either call a function marked with the noreturn attribute or transfer program control outside the guard statement’s enclosing scope using one of the following statements: return, break, continue, throw". https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html